# Gradle/Groovy: move copy closure to seperate util method

Tags: gradle, groovy

I have this custom gradle plugin that creates a tar file based on some custom specs:

```
tar.into("${project.name}-${project.version}"){
    into('lib'){
        from project.tasks.jar
        from project.configurations.runtime
    }

    //fix line endings for *.sh and *.conf files
    from("src/main/assembly"){
        include '**/*.sh'
        include '**/*.conf'
        filter(FixCrLfFilter, eol:FixCrLfFilter.CrLf.newInstance("unix")) // change line endings to unix format
        fileMode = 0744
        dirMode = 0755
    }

    //leave rest of the assembly untouched except for the filtered files above
    from("src/main/assembly"){
        exclude '**/*.sh'
        exclude '**/*.conf'
        fileMode = 0744
        dirMode = 0755
    }
}
```

I would like to extract the two "from("src/main/assembly")" blocks into a seperate util class so i can reuse them in another plugin. Something like this:

```
class AssemblyUtil {

    def static CopySpec assemblyFiles = copySpec {
        //fix line endings for *.sh and *.conf files
        from("src/main/assembly"){
            include '**/*.sh'
            include '**/*.conf'
            filter(FixCrLfFilter, eol:FixCrLfFilter.CrLf.newInstance("unix")) // change line endings to unix format
            fileMode = 0744
            dirMode = 0755
        }

        //leave rest of the assembly untouched except for the filtered files above
        from("src/main/assembly"){
            exclude '**/*.sh'
            exclude '**/*.conf'
            fileMode = 0744
            dirMode = 0755
        }
    }
}
```

And then be able to refactor the original method to:

```
tar.into("${project.name}-${project.version}"){
    into('lib'){
        from project.tasks.jar
        from project.configurations.runtime
    }

    with AssemblyUtil.assemblyFiles
}
```

That way i can reuse the closure block in other plugins.

It is not working. I am not sure of the syntax. Is this possible? Could anyone help me getting it right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess, but it might have something to do with defining the spec in a static context. Maybe the following does work:

```
class AssemblyUtil {

    def static CopySpec assemblyFiles(Project project) = project.copySpec {
        ...
    }
}
```

and then pass the project to this method

```
tar.into("${project.name}-${project.version}"){
    into('lib'){
        from project.tasks.jar
        from project.configurations.runtime
    }

    with AssemblyUtil.assemblyFiles(project)
}
```

Comment: The "problem" is that i do not have a project instance. It is just a simple util class

Comment: Yes, but you can pass it as an argument.

Comment: Sorry i misunderstood. But it gives compile error when trying the solution above.